# Kiel esperante diri "requirement" / "prerequisite" / "dependency" (de komputil-programo)

Tags: single-word-requests, information-technology

Sometimes, to use certain software, some other software needs to also be installed, or the computer has to fulfill certain properties. For these kinds of conditions, the terms "requirement" and "prerequisite" are usually used. (In Python application projects, it's even customary to have a file called `requirements.txt` that lists required Python packages in machine-readable form.)

Another English term that is sometimes used for this meaning (to distinguish it from the requirements you impose on the software in question (what it's supposed to do / solve — the requirements specification)) is "dependency".

Is there an Esperanto term for stuff (especially other software) a software depends on?

Answer (score 5):

[Komputeko](https://komputeko.net/index_eo.php?vorto=require) suggests the word *postulo* which is also the word that sprang to my mind. So I guess if Python were written in Esperanto the file could be called `postuloj.txt`.

It also has a suggested translation for *dependency*: *dependeco*. I’m not really sure why that ends in *-eco*. It would make more sense to me to say *dependaĵo*. If you Google this latter word you can find some examples of it being used, for example in the [Esperanto translation of rpm](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/rpm/blob/master/po/eo.po#L2537).

```
$ LANG=eo rpm --help
…
      --whatconflicts    mendi/konstati la pakaĵo(j)n, kiuj postulas dependaĵon
```

Comment: "I’m not really sure why that ends in -eco" Maybe because the English term "dependency" can refer to either the relationship / the fact that one thing depends on another (_-eco_) or on the dependee / the thing/artifact depended on (_-aĵo_ or maybe _-ato_ / _-ataĵo_?)

Comment: Is "postulo" not the word for the requirements imposed on a software (i.e., ~ its spec)? Or can it be used for both?

Comment: @das-g Yes, I don’t see why *postulo* couldn’t be used for both. The example above at least uses the verb form *postuli* in that sense.

Comment: @das-g Yes, I see what you mean about *dependeco*. It would be helpful if Komputeko gave more context and examples rather than just one-word translations.